# C# unable to execute the powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell

```
using (Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    runspace.Open();
    using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        Command lic1 = new Command("Out-String");
        var script1 = "$s = Get-LocalUser -Name test2";
        var script2 = "Remove-LocalUser -InputObject $s";
        string accessScriptPath = $"{script1} ;\n {script2}"; 
        powershell.Commands.AddCommand(lic1);
        powershell.Commands.AddCommand(new Command(accessScriptPath));
        var results = powershell.Invoke();
        PowerShellErrorCheck(powershell, results);
        powershell.Commands.Clear();
    }
}
```

I wants to execute the command and it was assigned to a variable and trying to access in next line but system throw exception. '$s = Get-LocalUser -Name test2 ;
 Remove-LocalUser -InputObject $s' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Mainly I was trying the above code was to simulate the below powershell code to c#

```
$x = Get-CsRgsAgentGroup -Identity service:ApplicationServer:atl-cs-001.litwareinc.com -Name "Help Desk"

$x.AgentsByUri.Add("sip:kenmyer@litwareinc.com")

Set-CsRgsAgentGroup -Instance $x
```

Comment: Use `AddScript`, not `AddCommand`.  `AddCommand` is expecting a cmdlet/function name.

Comment: I tried changing the code same error.string accessScriptPath = $"{script1} ;\n {script2}";
                        powershell.AddScript(accessScriptPath);
                        var results = powershell.Invoke();

Comment: Well you're trying to mix commands with scripts would be my guess.  Put everything into one or the other.

Comment: How to convert this into C# $x = Get-CsRgsAgentGroup -Identity service:ApplicationServer:atl-cs-001.litwareinc.com -Name "Help Desk"

$x.AgentsByUri.Add("sip:kenmyer@litwareinc.com")

Set-CsRgsAgentGroup -Instance $x

Comment: I removed the commands and added only addscript still getting the same error.

Comment: Add script with SetVariable worked for me. Thanks